# why the img cannot be centered vertically when i use vertical-align?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

the img cannot be centered vertically when i use vertical-align, I really dont understand why.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: blanchedalmond;
}

h1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
}

img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <img src="https://img01.yzcdn.cn/vant/cat.jpeg" />
  vertical-align middle
</h1>
```

Comment: PS: and `<h1><div></div></h1>` is an invalid HTML markup. `<div>` cant be a child of an `<h1>` tag.

Comment: @tacoshy `<div>` ***cannot*** be a child of an `<h1>` tag...

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have vertical align middle applied. You have posted it as text in your HTML but as such, it also only works as text but not as a code command.

Then, `vertical-align: center;` only works in combination with tables or table-cells. So you would need to apply: `display: table-cell;`. However, the more modern solution would be flexbox. Use: `h1 { display: flex; align-items: center; }` and the image will be vertically centered within the `<h1>` tag.

Then you have 2 issues:

The critical issue: `<h1><div></div></h1>` is an invalid HTML markup that will neither pass the W3C nor the WHATWG markup check. A `<div>` cannot be a child within a header tag.

The minor issue is with the `<img />` tag. Since HTML5 the image tag is an empty tag. Means it does not have a closing tag nor does it have a slash at the end. It's simply written `<img>`. Only a few frameworks/libraries still use the slash.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: blanchedalmond;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
}

img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <img src="https://img01.yzcdn.cn/vant/cat.jpeg" />
  vertical-align middle
</h1>
```

Comment: "Since HTML5 the image tag is an empty tag." — It was empty in HTML 3.2 and 4.x. In HTML is is void. (Which means the same thing, but it is a new name for it).  "Means it does not have a closing tag nor does it have a slash at the end. " — That means the end tag is forbidden but the `/` at the end of the start tag is *optional*.

Comment: I have edited my code, but its not the keypoint. I want to know why the img cannt be centered vertically, do not use other methods

Comment: chenguang see above it exactly explains why your code cant be vertically centered.

Comment: *only works in combination with tables or table-cells* --> this is not true. Vertical-align apply to inline level element in order to get aligned inside a linebox so they can be applied to image and text without the need for table-cell https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: @TemaniAfif right, as headings by default block level elements, it still wont apply to them. Feel free to edit my anwser to be more correct. You have my consent.

Comment: heading is irrelevant here since vertical-align is applied to the img which is the inline element. an inline element (img) inside a line-box that is inside a block level element (the heading)